# error context cannot be applied to adapterview.onitemclicklistener

Tags: android, facebook

I get error:

> getFacebookPageURL (android.content.Context) cannot be applied to (android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) with this

Here's my code:

```
public static String FACEBOOK_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/YourPageName";
public static String FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID = "YourPageName";

//method to get the right URL to use in the intent
public String getFacebookPageURL(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
        if (versionCode >= 3002850) { //newer versions of fb app
            return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL;
        } else { //older versions of fb app
            return "fb://page/" + FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return FACEBOOK_URL; //normal web url
    }
}
```

Then start an intent as follows:

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL(this);
facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

Comment: try "Activiy.this" rather that "this"

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL(MainActivity.this); //name of your activity
facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
MainActivity.this.startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

Because just `this` refers to `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` not `Activity` class. And `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` doesn't extend `Context`.